# Cannot pass GUID parameter to stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I can't figure out why I am getting this error.

Could anyone please help?

[image: GUID]

UPDATE:
Even adding the `@` character, the code still does not run.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

1. Include `@` in your parameter name
2. Set `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`
3. Set `p.DbType = DbType.Guid`

Comment: Only step 2 and 3 are necessary fix.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the parameter type. 
The equivalent of SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier is DbType.Guid